# Adding colored lines in a square grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I was wondering how would I draw red and blue lines in the hand drawn picture to the 4 times 4 grid generated by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (-1,-1) rectangle (6cm,6cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

additionally, I would like to add the vertex $v$ in the image as well.

Thus far, I have been able to produce the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
        {
            \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
            {
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
        
        
        
        % lines
        
        \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {2,...,4}{
            \draw[red!80!black] (circ-1-0) -- (circ-\i-3);
            \draw[red!80!black] (circ-1-0) -- (circ-\j-1);
        }

       
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

where I obtain the following image:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 5):

You were quite close to desired result:-). A simple, elementary solution using two loops is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt, 
              inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}    
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,4}
\node (n\i\j) [dot] at (\i,\j) {};
}
%
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\draw[blue] (n14) |- (n41);
\draw[red]  (n11) -- (n24)
            (n11) -- (n23)
            (n11) -- (n34)
            (n11) -- (n32)
            (n11) -- (n44)
            (n11) -- (n43)
            (n11) -- (n42);
}
\node[below left] at (n11) {$V$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated

Here, with `ifnum` tests according to TeX syntax, we draw the red segments as soon as the nodes are created.

[image: sreenshot]
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

```
\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
    {\foreach \y in {0,...,3}
        {\node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
          % lines
         \ifnum \x>0
            \ifnum \y>0
          \draw[red!80!black](0,0)--(.5*\x,.5*\y);  
          \fi\fi 
            }
        }
         
        \draw[blue!80!black](circ-0-0)--(circ-3-0)(circ-0-0)--(circ-0-3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

I have completed the loops in your code that suffice by doing this.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
  
\begin{document}        
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,...,3}
        {
            \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
            {
                \node(circ-\x-\y)[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] at (.5*\x,.5*\y) {};
            }
        }
         
        % lines
        \draw[blue!80!black](circ-0-0)--(circ-3-0)(circ-0-0)--(circ-0-3);
        \foreach \i  in {1,...,3}
            \foreach \j in {1,...,3}
            \draw[red!80!black] (circ-0-0) -- (circ-\i-\j);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can offer a slightly different option. Here I am trying to avoid overlapped lines, i.e. from the origin to (1,1), from the origin to (2,2), etc.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round]
\draw[blue](0,3) |- (3,0);
\draw[red] (0,0) -- (3,3);
\foreach \x/\y  in {1/3,1/2,2/3}
{%
  \draw[red] (\x,\y) -- (0,0) -- (\y,\x);
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} \foreach \y in {0,...,3}
{%
  \fill (\x,\y) circle (1.5pt);
}
\node at (0,0) [below left] {$V$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]